# Concise way of copying objects in Scala

Tags: scala, ocaml

OCaml exposes a concise syntax for copying records having a lot of fields.

```
type t = {
  x : int;
  y : int;
  z : int;
}

let _ =
  let v = {x = 1; y = 2; z = 3} in
  {v with z = 42}
```

Is there a similar syntax for Scala's case classes?

Comment: Sure, just use the `copy` method with the default arguments except the one you want to change. Like this: `v.copy(z=42)`.

Comment: minor question related to the utility of this, does using copy preserve row-type polymorphism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case classes define not just `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods, but also `copy`. Fortunately the `copy` method is defined in a way that the current values of the `this` object are the default parameters, but you can change any of them using named arguments. Your example would look like this:

```
case class Type(
  x : int,
  y : int,
  z : int,
)

val v = Type(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
v.copy(z=42)
```

But you can also use one of the lensing libraries too. (I think both scalaz and shapeless has one.)

Comment: scalaz may have or have had lenses and shapeless definitely does, but I think monocle is now the typelevel-recommended lens library.